# AWS Glue write only newest partitions parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a glue database that has two tables each with the same data just partitioned differently. I am trying to write a job that runs nightly, reads the data from one table, then writes the new data with the updated partitions. I can do that with the following code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "Database",
    table_name = "Table",
    transformation_ctx = "datasource0"
)

datasource0 = datasource0.toDF()

datasource0.write.partitionBy("Key1","Key2").parquet(OutputFilePath)
```

But this would take and write the whole data frame. I only want to write the new partitions, so I found the following snippet on AWS website:

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = projectedEvents,
    connection_type = "s3",    
    connection_options = {"path": "$outpath", "partitionKeys": ["type"]},
    format = "parquet")
```

But this just rewrites the whole data frame too. How can I just rewrite the newest partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the push_down_predicate argument. The data is partitioned originally by Year, Month, Day, and Hour, so I just subtracted one day and then used the push_down_predicate as follows:

```
timestamp = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
s1 = timestamp.split('-')

pdp = "partition_0 = " + s1[0] + " and partition_1 = " + s1[1] + " and partition_2 = " + s1[2]

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "mailfiles_standardized", 
    table_name = "firehoseoutput", 
    push_down_predicate = pdp
)

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame = datasource2,
connection_type = "s3",
connection_options = {
    "path": Bucket, 
    "partitionKeys": ["Key1","Key2"]
    },
format = "parquet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at bookmarks, which works like a checkpointing mechanism to avoid reprocessing data that has previously been processed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

Comment: Thanks @Eman, I actually found a solution by taking the current timestamp and creating a Push Down Predicate so I only ever load the previous day's partitions